# Conditional Compilation inside Literate Haskell

Tags: haskell, preprocessor, cabal, literate-programming

I have a literate haskell file and want to use conditional compilation. I use the bird style of literate programming. The following code does not work.

```
> #if MIN_VERSION_base(4,6,0)
> import Control.Exception
> #endif
```

I need a solution for cabal 1.14.0

**EDIT:**

[cpphs](http://projects.haskell.org/cpphs/) has an option --unlit which unlits literate sourcecode, but I don't know how to pass this option to cpphs in cabal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @kosmikus points out, you can simply put the C preprocessor directives outside any `>` or `\begin{code}` and they will work as expected – if they do not interfere with your processing of the non-code parts of your literal code.

You simply cannot use C preprocessor directives with bird-style literate programming, as the unlitting step replaces the `>` with a space, so you have no chance to get the `#` into the first column. You can verify this by passing `-keep-tmp-files` to GHC and checkout the generated `.lpp` file.

You can resort to `\begin{code}`...`\end{code}` blocks to get both, but if you mix them them with `>`-style lines of code, keep the extra space in mind and add it to your lines wrapped in `\begin{code}`...`\end{code}`:

```
> {-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

A literal comment

\begin{code}
#if MIN_VERSION_base(4,6,0)
  import Control.Exception
#endif
\end{code}

> main = return ()
```

Comment: Do you really have to switch to code blocks? Can't you put the CPP directives directly in the source file, without any preceding `>`?

Comment: Ups, I thought I tried that first, but indeed that is the case.